# Graypy not giving error when fake hostname given

Tags: python, python-2.7, graylog

I am trying to use Graylog-2.0.1. which is running on 192.168.0.23 on port 8093.
I have successfully implemented GELF UDP on host 192.168.0.23 with port 8093

```
import logging
import graypy
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = graypy.GELFHandler('192.168.0.23', port=8093)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info('Log Test 1 : CRITICAL -- info')
```

**This Code is Running. OK**

Now when change the host to 192.168.0.22 in my code it should give me error, But it is not giving me any error.

```
import logging
import graypy
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = graypy.GELFHandler('192.168.0.22', port=8093)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info('Log Test 1 : CRITICAL -- info')
```

**This code should give me Error like Graylog server is not running on this host.**
But No Error program executed successfully but no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is a stateless protocol. As long as the IP address can be routed, there's no way for the library to know whether there is a process listening on the given UDP port or not.

In other words: Everything works as designed.

Comment: i just want additional information. Is graypy only designed for UDP? because when my "input" was GELF TCP the same code wont work.

Comment: graypy supports GELF UDP and GELF AMQP according to https://graypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/